# response from server

Tags: xmlhttprequest, response

When I create request to the server:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction()
var ajaxRequest;
try{
ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
try{
} catch (e) {
try{
ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e){
alert("Your browser broke!");
return false;
}
}
```

}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

document.write(ajaxRequest.responseText);

document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "http://www.bbc.co.uk", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

}

```
</script>
```

Why response is nothing? Why response isnt html code of this web site?

Comment: Please explain more about your situation.  You would like us to spend our time answering your question.  The least you can do is spend some time to frame it properly.

Comment: sorry code of my question was missing...I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work (I don't have time to test it right now.)

```
function ajaxFunction() { //Added open {
    var ajaxRequest;
    try{
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
// Removed additional try / catch
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
        alert("Your browser broke!");
        return false;
        }
    } 
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.write(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }; // Added semi-colon to the end of the anonymous function definition
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "http://www.bbc.co.uk", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

A few notes:

- White space is not required for the most part in Javascript, but proper indentation makes it **much** easier to spot syntax errors.
- When you bind an attribute to an anonymous function you need to follow your `}` with a `;`
- Once you understand how this works, dig into one of the larger libraries ajax functions / modules. (Learning is always a good thing, and ajax is one of those areas that really needs a few dozen man-hours of work to encounter all the differences between browsers.)**`+`**

### **ADDENDUM:**

Cross-domain ajax requests are **very** difficult to do right (i.e. safely, securely, and without throwing errors) -- they are forbidden to javascript directly by the [Same-Domain Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196966/jquery-ajax-cross-domain-call-and-permission-issue) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752319/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-jquery-php) for more discussion on the subject and ways to get around it with a proxy or with `jsonp`

**`+`** jQuery's ajax function is **325 lines long** (and that's not counting `$.ajax.settings` or `$.extend()`)

Comment: it is the same, response came, but responseText is null

Comment: it is working when url is in the same domain for example url="something.html" but when it is cross site url it isnt working.

Comment: @john -- I updated my answer to briefly address cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a library like jQuery to do AJAX requests - they handle all the cross-browser quirks for you, and do a lot of extra work to boot. Your code could be as simple as

```
$.get(
  'http://www.bbc.co.uk',
  function(data) {
    // do something with data
  }
);`
```