# Authentication problem with Wufoo

Tags: php

I set up a [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/) form with admin only portions that will only show up if I am logged in. I read through the [Wufoo API documentation](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/) and I can get the authenication to work, but when I try to access the form after I authenticate, it says I need to authenticate. This is what I have so far (subdomain, api key & form id changed)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$curl1 = curl_init('http://fishbowl.wufoo.com/api/v3/users.xml');
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'AOI6-LFKL-VM1Q-IEX9:footastic');
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Wufoo Sample Code');

$response = curl_exec($curl1);
$resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl1);

if($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
    echo 'success!<br>';
} else {
    echo 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);
}

$curl2 = curl_init("http://fishbowl.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/w7x1p5/entries.json"); 
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl2);
curl_close ($curl2);
echo $response;

curl_close($curl1);

?>
```

It doesn't matter if I close `$curl1` before or after I call `$curl2`, I get the same message on my screen:

> success!
>
> You must authenticate to get
> at the goodies.

and I know the api, subdomain and form id are all correct.

And one last bonus question... can I do all of this using Ajax instead? - the page I will be displaying the form on will already be limited to admin access, so exposing the API shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I did some digging around.

Here's the thing, you need to authenticate for every call you want to make to the API.
I noticed that in the URL that you used (`http://fishbowl.wufoo.com/api/v3/users.xml`) , you used `http` but the API requires you to use `https`. You will only get that `You must authenticate to get at the goodies.` message if you attempt to access through the normal HTTP protocol.

So for your second call, you need to re-authenticate again.

Your code should then look like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$curl1 = curl_init('https://fishbowl.wufoo.com/api/v3/users.xml');
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'AOI6-LFKL-VM1Q-IEX9:footastic');
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Wufoo Sample Code');

$response = curl_exec($curl1);
$resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl1);

if($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
    echo 'success!<br>';
} else {
    echo 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);
}

$curl2 = curl_init("https://fishbowl.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/w7x1p5/entries.json"); 
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'AOI6-LFKL-VM1Q-IEX9:footastic');
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Wufoo Sample Code');
$response = curl_exec($curl2);
curl_close ($curl2);
echo $response;

curl_close($curl2);

?>
```

Regarding your question about all these being done in AJAX, it's not possible at the moment because Wufoo does not support JSONP callbacks (which allow for cross domain AJAX requests). (If you don't know what I'm talking about read [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196966/jquery-ajax-cross-domain-call-and-permission-issue)) However, if you want to plug this functionality into AJAX, you can do an AJAX call to your PHP script on the local server. The PHP script will do something like the above, authenticating with Wufoo.

Comment: Hi sirhc! Thanks for your answer, sadly my free web host has safe mode set, so I can't access any secure URLs. But your answer does work for me if I use `http://` but apparently I'm still not authorized to view the admin only data; though, I am receiving the public data now. So thanks!... I guess I need to go in search of another free php hosting site that doesn't have safe mode set.

Comment: Hmmm, actually I checked my hosting service and safe mode is off... when I use `https://` the page never completes loading. And if I set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to true, I get this error: `curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in...`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo above where I used `$curl1` instead of `$curl2`. It might be due to those options not being set that's why it's not returning. :)

Comment: Actually I noticed the typos and fixed them already... when I try to access any `https://` site, the page never finishes loading. I'm guessing it's a host setting.